# Why There are Several Database Models?

Tags: database, database-design

Why do we have multiple database models when one of them is already doing the job. How/Why did we come up with these several models? e.g. Object model, hierarchy model, relational, etc.
In other words, how these models came up?

Comment: a flat file ought to be good enough for anyone.

Comment: For example? Relational and object relational? Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different database types (what I'm assuming you mean by models...RDBMS, Object Databases, Key-Value Pair Databases, etc.) because no one type fits every need perfectly.

Relational Database Models are good at storing and retrieving relational data. Not all data is relational though.

OLAP (Online Analytical Processing) cubes lend themselves to analyzing time related data which is something a RDBMS will struggle greatly with.

Object Databases are good at persisting objects and defining/dealing with object oriented issues (inheritance, polymorphism, etc.). That is something a flat file, RDBMS, or OLAP cube can't give you naturally.

...the list goes on.